# How to apply color to row number cell in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Hi jqGrid developers/users,

I have a requirement to validate the row data before submitting to database. I successfully validated and got the row Ids which are failed in validation. Now I want to change the color of the corresponding row "Row number" cell. I have checked the "setCell" but this method has a column name parameter to pass.

I want to apply color for "rownumber" cell as shown in below image.

[image: Applying color to rownumber cell]

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use applytoRow property fo Jqgrid

Comment: I didnt find applytoRow property anywhere. Could you share some piece of code or link.